# Images slider that jump 1 step each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am looking for some JQuery script with no success so far. I have a 1000 px width div, inside that div i want to add 10 divs horizontal, but to display only 4 divs. When the user will click the right arrow, all divs will move to the left and 1 new image will appear. For example, in the div there is a focus on div 2,3,4,5 after click on right arrow the focus will change to 3,4,5,6 and so on.
When images ending the focus will be 5,6,7,1 and so on. any idea? PLEASE[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a JS carousal. There are many options available depending on what you're looking for.

You can adjust the width of the carousal as you like in the CSS and also initialize it to have as many elements as you like.

Here are a few that I've used in the past

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

Cheers and happy coding!